# Definition of logarithmic capacity

Tags: real-analysis, mathematical-physics, potential-theory

In the definition of logarithmic capacity of a compact set $E$ in the plane, the Robin constant is defined to be  $V(E)=\inf\int_E\int_E \log\frac{1}{|z-w|} d\mu(z)d\mu(w)$ where $\inf$ is taken over all probability measures $\mu$ with supp$(\mu)\subset E$. Here is my question. Can infimum be taken not only over positive probability measures but over all "nice enough" signed measures with total variation one? say like $d\lambda= fdm$ where $f\in L^2(E)$ ,and $dm$ is Lebesgue measure. If so does that change our infimum meaning Robin constant ?if it changes, does it stay positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered for more general case.[here, cf. Theorem 16.4.2.](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=rY8__WxS2zsC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=hille+analytic+function+theory&ots=-e7Z6lAAQL&sig=cENLQ-Su-2PNhb0sE1bdG9iBUp4#v=onepage&q=hille%20analytic%20function%20theory&f=false) It basically states that if $\sigma $ is a signed measure with $\sigma(E)=0$, $S\subset E$ and $I(\sigma)$ is absolutely convergent. Then $I(\sigma)\geq 0$